# Checkbox in JTable does not print in Windows LookAndFeel

Tags: java, swing, jtable, look-and-feel

I have a JTable which has column classes as Integer, String and Boolean. The boolean class gives me the column in a form of checkbox in JTable.

I try to print the JTable using JTable.print().
Whenever I print the table in Java native lookAndFeel, everything prints correctly
but whenever I try to print the JTable in WindowsLookAndFeel, the checkboxes are missing.
I am new to programming, therefore I don't know where I am doing wrong.
I am attaching the code and screenshots below:

```
package swing;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTable.PrintMode;
import javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;


public class TableExample extends JFrame{
    
    public TableExample() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        
        JButton print = new JButton("Print Table");
        Object[][] data = {
                {1, "HAIER", Boolean.TRUE},
                {2, "SAMSUNG", Boolean.FALSE},
                {3, "LG", Boolean.TRUE}
        };
        
        String[] columns = {"S No.", "Company", "Currently Available?"};
                
        
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columns) {
            
            @Override
            public int getRowCount() {
                return data.length;
            }
            
            @Override
            public int getColumnCount() {
                return columns.length;
            }
            
            @Override
            public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                return data[rowIndex][columnIndex];
            }
            
            @Override
            public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
                return columns[columnIndex];
            }
            
            @Override
            public Class<?> getColumnClass (int columnIndex){
                return data[0][columnIndex].getClass();
            }
            
            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
                return false;
            }
        };
        JTable table = new JTable(model);
        table.setFillsViewportHeight(true);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(600, 300));
        
        try {
            for(LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if("Windows".equals(info.getName())) {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        getContentPane().add(panel);
        panel.add(new JScrollPane(table), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.add(print, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        
        print.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try
                {
                    table.print(PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH);
                }catch(Exception ee) {
                    ee.printStackTrace();
                }
                
            }
        });
        
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
        
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TableExample();
                
            }
        });
    }
}
```

[Windows Look and Feel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vBb4T.png)

[Java Look and Feel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nmIL.png)

Comment: 1.) What java version do you have?

Comment: The Java Tutorial on [How To Set the Look and Feel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html#dynamic) specifies that after changing the look and feel after startup, you should use `SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(frame);`. Maybe try this out and check if it changes anything, as I can't check myself right now.

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation of the TableModel is wrong and is unnecessary.

The data for any model should be defined as instance variables of the model. The columns names and data should NOT be defined outside of the model.

The DefaultTableModel already provides its own storage and implementation of the TableModel methods. There is no need for you to override all the methods of the model. You only need to override the methods that you need to customize. In your case it looks like you need to override the `getColumnClass()` and `isCellEditable()` methods.

So your code should be something like:

```
    String[] columnNames = ...
    Object[][] data = ...

    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames)
    {
        @Override
        public Class getColumnClass(int column)
        {
            for (int row = 0; row < getRowCount(); row++)
            {
                Object o = getValueAt(row, column);

                if (o != null)
                    return o.getClass();
            }

            return Object.class;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column)
        {
            ...
        }

    };

    JTable table = new JTable(model);
```

Note, the `getColumnClass(...)` method will handle the case where you might have a null value in the TableModel. Your implementation is fine for your example.

Don't know if this will fix your Windows problem.

Comment: Glad it helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark (beside the answer) so people know the problem has been solved.